# Publishing Azure Functions with large binary dependencies

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have an F# project on Azure Functions with a dependency on a large binary file `pandoc.exe`. Currently I am publishing the function with Azure Functions Core Tools using:

`func azure functionapp publish <function app name>`

In the .fsproj I added:

```
<Content Include="pandoc.exe">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

This works, however I notice it uploads the full zip bundle ~25MB each time I publish. As pandoc is unchanged and >99% of the bundle size I am wondering if there is a way to only publish my dll and keep the existing exe as it is unchanged?

Comment: Why not to store that on blob storage and then on AF start just download it?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me but not sure how to do that?

Comment: @tranquility I would definitely follow Bowmans Zhu advice and just make CI/CD with azure pipeline its super quick, it will be faster then doing via blob since 1. you will need to write code, 2. Startup will be slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only upload the .dll each time(Or called incremental deployment). Then you can take a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment

And also, if your function app is based on windowOS, then you can use [ftp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal) or storage file share to upload the file.

Comment: I'm using VS Code and deploying on the in-built terminal (PowerShell). Continuous / incremental deployment sounds like the way to go once I get it set up.

Comment: @BowmanZhu i think OP concern is that they deploy from their machine and its slow